# Echo filter with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, echo, signal-processing

How can I obtain echo effect with SciPy?

Here's my code, but this sound doesn't resemble echo.
Which filters should i use?

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

sample_rate, data = wavfile.read('sound.wav')


b, a = signal.butter(3, 0.05)
output_signal = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)

wavfile.write('output.wav', sample_rate, output_signal)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(data,'b')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(output_signal,'r')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('amplitude')
plt.show()
```

Comment: you need a delay of > ~50 ms to start to get 'echo'  for off line processing you could just index back a few ksamples in your .wav data, maybe filter, reduce level add it to your leading data output

Comment: https://imgur.com/rk4kK0t  I added next signals, but i have problem with reducing them. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: just multiply by a constant < 1.0 before adding,  for more realism you probably want later 'echos' attenuated more than early ones

Comment: output_signal = np.copy(data)
for i in range(9,0,-1):
 output_signal = np.append(output_signal,data * float(i/10))
https://imgur.com/a/tfG9o Should i add them in other way?